# PowerShell: Filter list of file names using list of forbidden characters

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV with a list of file names that I built using Get-ChildItem.
Now I want to take that list and create a list of items with file names that include certain characters (",|,',<, etc...)

I wrote the following script which works well; except I am not able to filter file with a ? in the file name. I would also like to make it a little cleaner and more straightforward. Any ideas?

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\FILES.CSV

$csvexport = $null

$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*'*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*%*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*|*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*#*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*:*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*<*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*>*"})

$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*/*"})
$csvExport = $csvexport + ($csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*\*"})

$csvexport | export-csv .\filesupdated.csv -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

Comment: Please edit your question so the code has proper formatting.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Done! Didn't realize the hash sign would make it bold. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RegEx (short for Regular Expression) match instead of the `-like` comparative operator. The following will try to match any of the characters that you listed, as well as the question mark and double quotation mark. The preceeding backslash is an escape character, to make sure that it is a literal match, and the pipe between each character mean 'or' so it looks for any of the characters.

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\FILES.CSV

$csvexport = $null

$csvExport = $csv | select name,length |Where-Object {$_.name -match "\`"|\'|\%|\||\#|\:|\<|\>|\/|\\|\?"}

$csvexport | export-csv .\filesupdated.csv -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

Some of the characters may not need to be escaped, but there is no harm (that I know of) in escaping a character even if it doesn't need it, unless you are trying to use it for a special character's purpose, which we aren't.